# How to display images from user folder in public storage link on laravel

Tags: php, image, laravel, storage

I have a Laravel app with a storage link to the public folder, and I'm trying to display an image in the view of the app. However, I'm not sure how to do so with the way the storage folder is structured.

Basically, the folder starts with the user's name, then has sub-folders, such as contacts, files, images, etc. The app is supposed to display the user's image within the src tag for the profile view.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <img class="profileImage" src="{{ url('storage/{{ Auth::user()->name }}/images/{{ $profileImage }}') }}" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; float: left; border-radius: 10%; margin-right: 25px;">
            <h2>{{ Auth::user()->name }}</h2>
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ route('profile.update') }}" method="post">
                <label>Update Profile</label>
                <input type="file" name="profileImage" id="profile-image">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                <input type="submit" class="pull-right btn btn-sm btn-primary">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried directing to a link within the url: `

```
{{ url('storage/app/public/{{ Auth::user()->name }}/images/{{ $profileImage }}`
```

However, when I load the page, the image is not displayed, or even saved. Is this the proper way to load the image from the view function?`

```
public function getUserProfile()
{
    return view('users.profile', ['user' => Auth::user()]);
}`
```

How should the program load the image from the user folder in storage?

`

Comment: Are you using the public disk? Have you read the docs on retrieving the urls? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem

Comment: I know how to use the urls with storage on laravel. I'm trying to see how to put the file variable inside of the image path within the view.

Comment: Okay. Can you update the code in your question using the actual way you're supposed to retrieve the file urls then? Because you're not supposed to build the urls yourself, like you're doing. Hint; it may involve `Storage::disk('public')->url('...')`.

Comment: I've edited the code to include the link url.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not point to correct folder path. You could try this

```
url('storage/app/public/{{ Auth::user()->name }}/images/{{ $profileImage }}')
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. The closing brackets are interpreted by the IDE as the closing brackets for the 'url' tag.

Comment: I tried using a slug to get the program to recognize the user file, but it still doesn't display the photo on the app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use symbolic link to access the data.

```
php artisan storage:link
```

refer : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem

Comment: I tried using a manually made uploads folder before, and the profile image was shown. I'm trying to figure out how to do the same with a storage link.